# Keyboard covers EditText when edittext having focus

Tags: android

I have a problem with keyboard and edittext in android.
My case:

- EditText has no focus,  I click EditText =>  Software Keyboard has displayed, edittext has focus and is moved up
- Then i click back button => keyboard hide, edittext still has focus
- I click edittext again => keyboard show, but edittext is covered by keyboard.

UPDATE

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="vn.com.fss.vndirect.TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My question: Why edittext is not move up like the first time, and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Where is code implementation ?

Comment: add in `Manifest file` this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Comment: read about `android:windowSoftInputMode`

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya
i tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
but not worked.
Pls, show me the details

Comment: @giang.ngo `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Answer (score 1):

Use this custom Edittext class. It will removes Edittext focus when back button is pressed

```
 public class KeyboardEditText extends EditText
 {
 public KeyboardEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
 }

public KeyboardEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public KeyboardEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
    super.setOnTouchListener(l);
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (listener != null)
        listener.onStateChanged(this, true);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (listener != null)
            listener.onStateChanged(this, false);

        // Hide cursor
        setFocusable(false);

        // Set EditText to be focusable again
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}

/**
 * Keyboard Listener
 */
KeyboardListener listener;

public void setOnKeyboardListener(KeyboardListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface KeyboardListener {
    void onStateChanged(KeyboardEditText keyboardEditText, boolean showing);
}
}
```

Comment: I've been thinking this way
But do you know why edittext not move up in the second time?
Thanks for answer.

Comment: because when you press back button, Edittext does not release its focus, so when you again open keyboard for same edittext it will not scroll up. This custom edittext removes focus from edittext when you press back button.

Comment: Oh, i get it,
Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is make your layout scrollable by inserting the master layout in your layout file inside `scrollView`. Try it and let me if it doesn't work. For example:

```
<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true"
      >
     <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
            <!--Your Layout content-->
     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This will basically scroll up your `editText` above the keyboard whenever your keyboards is displayed.

Comment: Pls, show me your code,
i tried, but not worked.what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you add `android:fillViewport` in your scrollView?

Comment: You are supposed to keep your layout which is inside scrollView, height as wrap_content. Make height of LinearLayout as wrap_content to make scrollView work properly.